# How to specify which ELF section to use in a Rust dylib

Tags: rust, elf

I can create a shared object using the Rust `dylib` crate type, but could not figure out how to specify the ELF `.init` section. I have a C program which loads a shared object with `dlopen()` and the shared object will register something like a callback function at `.init`. Compilation fails if I write:

```
#[no_mangle]
pub extern fn _init() {
    ...
```

then,

```
test.0.rs:(.text._init+0x0): multiple definition of `_init'
```

How do I specify the ELF section (like GCC's `constructor` attribute) or is there another way to specify a function which will be called just after a `.so` has loaded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The direct answer is to use the `#[link_section = "foo"]` attribute.

I tried to reverse engineer what GCC creates on OS X to replicate it:

```
pub extern fn do_a_thing() {
    println!("I was called by .init");
    cool_code();
}

#[link_section = "__DATA,__mod_init_func"]
pub static CONSTRUCTOR: extern fn() = do_a_thing;

fn cool_code() {
    println!("I'm just some code");
}
```

This does actually print both lines when it is loaded with `dlopen`, but then the whole program has a segmentation fault. I don't know enough of the details around this early initialization to completely narrow it down.

Actually, it might be [this bug](https://github.com/nagisa/rust_libloading/issues/5), which indicates the problem might just be because of internal data structures used in `println!`.

Comment: It works fine with `[link_section = ".ctors"]` in my case, thanks.